# How we can get output for os.system() in python?

Tags: python, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I wrote the following command in  Geoserver rest-api using curl:

```
cmd=curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XGET -H "Accept: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/datastores/mydatastore/featuretypes?list=available
```

I want to execute this command through python like os.system(cmd).
Now How can I get the list in python itself.
I tried as follow:

```
import subprocess
import os
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT,call
cmd=r"""curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XGET -H "Accept: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/datastores/mydatastore/featuretypes?list=available"""  
p=sybprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=None,shell=True)   
output=p.communicate()  
print output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice using a library for using REST from python, eg requests
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/datastores/mydatastore/featuretypes?list=available', auth=('admin', 'geoserver'))
```

then use r.text or r.json

Answer (score 1):

it is recommended to use subprocess.call()

cmd must be a list, so you should write it like :

```
cmdlist= ["curl", "-v", "-u", "admin:geoserver", "-XGET" ,"-H", "Accept: text/xml", "http//jdkjdf"]
```

note that you can use .split(" ") to create the list based on your variable cmd